# Trouble tagging object in S3 with php SDK 3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to set a tag on an object in an AWS S3 bucket using the AWS PHP SDK V3. I can read them OK once I manually set, by doing the following:

```
$objecttagged = $s3client->getObjectTagging([
 'Bucket' => 'mybucketname',
 'Key' => $myobject['Key'],
]);
```

I've looked through the docs on AWS and on the web but nothing seems to work. Closest I can figure is:

```
$result = $s3client->putObject([
 'Bucket' => 'mybucketname',
 'Key' => $myobject['Key'],
 'Tagging' => 'status=ready'
]);
```

But doing this just creates a version of the object name with zero byte size.
I assume you can add tagging to a buckets object programatically?

Has anyone got a link to docs I've missed or can confirm it can be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `putObject` call doesn't have a Body, hence you're uploading a zero-sized object. So, correct that and your object will be uploaded with tags.

If you want to apply tags *after* your object has been uploaded then call [PutObjectTagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobjecttagging). For example:

```
$result = $client->putObjectTagging([
    'Bucket' => 'mybucket',
    'Key' => 'mykey',
    'Tagging' => [
        'TagSet' => [
            [
                'Key' => 'status',
                'Value' => 'ready',
            ],
            [
                'Key' => 'owner',
                'Value' => 'elvis',
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and you are spot on with this answer - works a treat.

I hadn't added the  'TagSet' => [ part of the script and this seemed to just re-create the file, but with no content to it. Hence the zero byte size.

Hope this helps others in the future.